# Masters thesis topics in Applied probability and Probabilistic models in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

I'm looking for a topic for my masters thesis. Machine learning is my primary domain and I want to work on probabilistic models and applied probability in Machine Learning. Please suggest some exciting new topics that would make for a good masters thesis subject.
Anything related to Markov chains Monte Carlo, Bayesian methods, Probabilistic graphical models, Markov models and so on in context of machine learning would be great!

Comment: NASA approximates the position of planets and satellites and publishes these approximations online with a known margin of error. Using this margin of error, calculate the chances that some catastrophic event will occur in n years (eg, an asteroid hitting the Earth)